# Running __init__.py code in a Python package without importing the package?

Tags: python, import, lint, python-packaging

I am using an external package (`package_a`) that includes code in its root `__init__.py` file, which overrides and extends the behavior of classes from another package (`package_b`).
More concretely, upon importing `package_a` within my code, I can now benefit from the extended functionalities of `package_b` without ever using the import of `package_a` within my file.
I am wondering if there is a better, standard way to do this, without having a "falsely" unused import in my code (for linting and readability purposes) ?

Comment: Altering the behavior of a package by merely importing another package sounds like a very bad design choice in the good case and a debugging nightmare in the bad case

Comment: If you're worried about readability, I'd put that code in a function so that you have to call it explicitly after importing `package_b`.  Call it something descriptive (like `package_b.monkeypatch_package_a()`) so it'll be obvious what it does.

Comment: Yeah it is both bad design and horrible to debug but that's how `package_a` is designed and I don't really have an alternative

Comment: You could also wrap the `import` in your own function, and then put linter suppressions and a big comment block in that function.  That way other code at least isn't forced to use the weird "import with side effects" pattern.